# batchGet запрос google spreadsheets api c#

Tags: c#, google-spreadsheet

Необходимо доставать информацию из таблицы гугл, использую apis v4 для c#. У них в примере есть простой запрос на определенный диапазон ячеек.

```
        // Define request parameters.
        String spreadsheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
        String range = "Class Data!A2:E";
        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
                service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);
```

В строке range мы передаем наш диапазон. Но проблема в том, что необходимо получить объединенный диапазон. Например: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли у кого пример данного batchGet запроса для c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так (весь код приводить не буду, он стандартный):

```
// Define request parameters.
const string spreadsheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
const string range1 = "Class Data!B2:B7";
const string range2 = "Class Data!D2:E7";
SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.BatchGetRequest request
  = service.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchGet(spreadsheetId);

request.Ranges = new Repeatable<string>(new[] { range1, range2 });

BatchGetValuesResponse response = request.Execute();
IList<IList<object>> values = response.ValueRanges.SelectMany(x => x.Values).ToList();


if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Name, Major");
  foreach (var row in values)
  {
    if (row.Count > 1)
      Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", row[0], row[1]);
    else
      Console.WriteLine("{0}", row[0]);
  }
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
}
```

Результат для таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Будет:

```
Name, Major
Female
Male
Female
Female
Male
Male
CA English
SD Math
NC English
SD Art
WI English
MD Art
```

Comment: Спасибо за рабочий пример, есть 2 нюанс. По дефолту он получает ячейки сначала построчно, а с объединенным диапазоном он работает сначала с 1, а потом со 2. Есть ли какой-нибудь параметр, чтобы объединенный диапазон воспринимался как единый? И допустим рассматривалось в таком порядке(B2,D2,E2) потом переход на следующую строчку (B3,D3,E3) Это по скрину в ответе

Comment: @JohnSmith, да, вы можете использовать для этого метод `Zip` из `System.Linq`